# Trying to add CSS counter increment to figure captions in WordPress blog

Tags: css, wordpress, counter

I want to add basic auto counter functionality to my figure captions (which are marked up with <figcaption> tags) in a WordPress blog. So I added the following CSS code to the style.css file:

```
body {
  counter-reset: figure;
}

figcaption:before {
  content: "Figure " counter(figure) ": ";
  counter-increment: figure;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Well it didn't work (no generated content was added). Can anyone familiar with WordPress tell me what's missing? I tested this code on a regular webpage and it works fine. Perhaps WordPress doesn't support CSS counters?

Thanks

Comment: Does this not work in any browser at all? It almost definitely has nothing to do with WordPress.

Comment: @BoltClock It does work here: http://jsfiddle.net/blineberry/c8cHW/
Bill, can you give us a link to page where this isn't working?

Comment: WordPress doesn't have any choice about what CSS it "supports" or doesn't. That is all browser. I am guessing you have a conflict with another CSS rule. Can you post an URL to the problem page?